Trying to buy more shares(or double down) when my next_purchase target is met and when im already in a trade in Tradingview
i have this script im creating that is using a channel breakout to determine when i go long on condition based on if the current price is greater than the highest 50 day cloeses, and i sell when the close is less than the 50 days lows.
The problem im having is when im in a trade and it keeps going up, i would like to buy more shares, however that condition to buy more is never met.
i noticed when i was troubleshooting this in a different different that the long_additonal entry to buy more was only met if the strategy_position_size == 0 and when commented out the update for the next_purchase price after i bought in
in the picture the green plus signs are suppose to be the next_purchase

here is my script
lookback = input.int(title="Length", minval=1, maxval=1000, defval=100)
atr_length = input.int(21, title="ATR Length")
atrMultiplier = input.int(3, title="ATR Multiplier")
risk_per_trade = input.float(5, title="risk percentage")

// Variables
float atr = ta.atr(atr_length)
float atr_value = atr * atrMultiplier

// Calculate stop loss values
var float trailing_stop = na
var float next_purchase = na

longCondition = close > ta.highest(close, lookback)[1] 
sellCondition = close < ta.lowest(close, lookback)[1]

if(longCondition and strategy.position_size == 0 and time_cond)

    // caclculate risk per trade
    float risk_amount = strategy.initial_capital * (risk_per_trade / 100)
    // calculate amount of shares to purchase
    float amount_of_shares = risk_amount / atr_value
   
   // buy
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, qty=amount_of_shares)
   
    if (na(trailing_stop))
        trailing_stop := close - atr_value


    if (na(next_purchase))
        next_purchase = close + atr_value



// executes condition if close hits next_purchase
if ( strategy.position_size >= 1 and close > next_purchase)
    float risk_amount = strategy.initial_capital * (risk_per_trade / 100)
    float amount_of_shares = risk_amount / atr_value
    strategy.entry("Long_additonal", strategy.long, qty=amount_of_shares)


    // Update next_purchase after buying additional shares
    next_purchase := close + atr_value


tried changing the lookback period to something smaller to see if it would buy when the trend is going up
2) i tried to change the condition to only when the strategy.position_size is >=1 and close > next_purchase, however the long_Additional is never met and it only works if the strategy_position_size == 0 . i also noticed it always buy after the sell, and not in between the long and sell, which is weird because unless the next_purchase price calculation is wrong, it should've bought at the green plus signs


Have you tried the strategy function's pyramiding parameter? By default, it's set to 1. If you want to buy more in the same direction, you can set it to 2, allowing it to buy again. However, if you're unsure how many times you want to buy, you should use strategy.order instead of strategy.entry

@Manish Pushpam, thanks for the suggestion, i was trying to find the order strategy command online, but i couldn't seem to find it, ill try that out and do research on the pyramiding parameter to see if that would work for my strategy possibly, thanks for replying
